# Count function is not working in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, uisegmentedcontrol

hi i am new to swift and ios and having an issue here. I have 3 different tableviews which I am calling from segementedController.

Everything is working fine but everytime I press any tab on segemented controller it prints monday. It only counts the data of table 1.

```
@IBOutlet weak var d1 : UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var d2 : UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var d3 : UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var segementedControlAction: UISegmentedControl!


var Names = ["Name1", "Name2","Name3","Name4"]
var Images =  ["1.jpg","2.jpg","5.jpg","8.jpg"]
var set =  ["14","15","16","17"]

var Names1 = ["Name5", "Name6","Name7"]
var Images1 =  ["6.jpg","4.jpg","7.jpg"]
var set1 =  ["4","5","6"]

var Names2 = ["Name9", "Name12","Name13","Name14"]
var Images2 =  ["11.jpg","21.jpg","51.jpg","81.jpg"]
var set2 =  ["114","115","116","117"]


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
var count: Int = 0
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true

if (tableView == self.d1) {
    print("Monday")
    count = self.Names.count
}
else if (tableView == self.d2) {
    print("Tuesday")
    count = self.Names1.count
}
else if (tableView == self.d3) {
    print("Wednesday")
    count = self.Names2.count
}

return count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
UITableViewCell {

let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
    indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

if segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
cell.nameLabel.text = Names[indexPath.row]
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])
cell.setLabel.text = set[indexPath.row]

}

else if segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

cell.nameLabel.text = Names1[indexPath.row]
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: Images1[indexPath.row])
cell.setLabel.text = set1[indexPath.row]
}


else {segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 2

cell.nameLabel.text = Names2[indexPath.row]
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: Images2[indexPath.row])
cell.setLabel.text = set2[indexPath.row]

}

return cell }
```

EDIT: App crashes whenever i select 2nd tab of segemented controller

Comment: That doesn't mean count is not working, it means your comparison between `tableView` and `d1` is always returning `true`.

Comment: ok so how can i reslove that issue.

Comment: Without knowing more information I couldn't say. Presumably `d1` is a reference to a table view?

Comment: i have added few more lines of code. do you have enough information now

Comment: What error do you get for the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    if segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        print("Monday")

        return self.Names.count 
    }

   else if segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

        print("Tuesday")

            return self.Names1.count

    }
     else if segementedControlAction.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 { 
       print("Wednesday")

        return self.Names2.count

    }
}
```

Comment: If you take a second to format your code it is a lot more helpful for future readers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simplify it

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableView.count
}
```

Comment: That works for 1 table. i have 3 tables how to handle count for them.